# How to update a sql table only if other condition exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 sql separated tables in my database:

```
ds_users, containing: group_id
```

and

```
ds_users_data_members, containing: data_gender
```

I would like to set / Update the `group_id` to `6` for all `data_gender` equal to `2`.

All this morning i tried to solve this issue , without success.

Please help. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the connection between the tables? Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements as well as some sample data as DML statements.

Comment: Mysql or sqlserver ? - update statement is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming there must be a relation between those two tables. *Without any relationship you cannot update record in one table by checking condition in another table.*

let's say `ds_users` table has column `user_id` which is also exist in `ds_users_data_members` table.

so, you can write following query to update all records in `ds_users` for `data_gender=2` in `ds_users_data_members` table

**[SQL SERVER EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/702bb)**

```
UPDATE    T
SET       group_id=6
FROM      ds_users T INNER JOIN ds_users_data_members T1 ON T.user_id=T1.user_id
WHERE     T1.data_gender=2
```

**[MySQL EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8c7/1)**

```
UPDATE    ds_users T INNER JOIN ds_users_data_members T1 ON T.`user_id`=T1.`user_id`
SET       T.`group_id`=6
WHERE     T1.`data_gender`=2;
```

You can replace the column name of `user_id` what you have given in your table.

Comment: This should work on sql server, but I doubt if it will work on MySql.

Comment: First thank you so much for reply. In the first table ds_users I have user_id and in the second table ds_users_data_members I have profile_id, with identical values. I still do not understand what are T and T1 values. Should i replace them withe the table one and table two names ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes exactly it was for Sql Server.. so, I have updated my answer

Comment: @CristinaAvramescu those are alias (you can say temporary short name of table or field to reduce the complexity in your sql query)

Comment: @CristinaAvramescu you must have at least one field which must be exist in both tables. For example, the user A has id 1 then it should be exist in another table to map the records between two tables.

Comment: THANK YOU so much. I renamed temporary the column: profile_id from the second table, to: user_is and i run the second command  you wrote, and like charm, it works. Now I will rename back the profile_id to user_id in the second table and this will be solved. Each day we learn something.